# trim(both) doesnt not trim the leading character

Tags: mysql, sql

Table qqq:

```
|**type**  | **ColB** |

-+-----------+-----------+-    
| A     | 0030-0000     |    
| A     | 0234-0001     |    
| A     | 0001-0003     |
```

`type` is `Varchar`,
`ColB` is `Varchar`

I would like to trim all zeroes in leading and trailing poisition. The expected outcome is :

```
|**type**  | **ColB** |

-+-----------+-----------+-    
| A     | 30-        |    
| A     | 234-0001   |    
| A     | 1-0003     |
```

This is query I wrote:

`select type, TRIM(both '0' FROM colB) From qqq
where type = 'A';`

However, my output is:

```
|**type**  | **ColB** |

-+-----------+-----------+-    
| A     | 0030-         |    
| A     | 0234-0001     |    
| A     | 0001-0003     |
```

the `trim (both` does not working out...

Comment: Presumably you have another character before the first `0`.

Comment: Nope. I've checked @GordonLinoff

Comment: BOTH is optional here, as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim

Comment: Stabbing in the dark here, but have you tried testing it with a string that does not have a -?

Comment: Even if i use 'TRIM(leading` it does not working out too @toonice

Comment: Does not have hyphen? @toonice

Comment: That's what I meant.  I have since gotten my copy of MySQL up and running and been able to test that theory.  It's not the hyphen.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: any possible alternatives? @toonice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139430/discussion-between-toonice-and-user6308605).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much diagnosis via chat I began to suspect that there was a leading space in the strings.  I suggested the following as an answer...

```
SELECT TRIM( '0' FROM TRIM( fieldName ) )
FROM tableName;
```